# How to insert in postgres Array Column using python Psycopg2 and parameter binding?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, array-column

Following is my table structure in postgresql:

```
CREATE TYPE lang AS ENUM ('english','hindi','marathi');
CREATE TABLE assignment (
    title varchar(100),
    ids lang[]
);
```

I want to insert a record in assignment table using parameter binding in python. I tried below code:

```
cursor.execute('insert into assignment (title, ids) values (%s, %s)',["person1",["english","hindi"]])
```

But it generates invalid query like:

```
insert into assignment (title, ids) values ('person1', ARRAY['english','hindi'])
```

And hence I get syntax error in query.

Correct query is:

```
insert into assignment (title, ids) values ('person1', '{"english","hindi"}')
```

Can someone let me know way to generate correct query using parameter binding?

Comment: That is valid array syntax. What is the error message?

Comment: ERROR: column "ids" is of type lang[] but expression is of type text[]

Answer (score 4):

Cast the passed array to `lang[]`:

```
cursor.execute('''
    insert into assignment (title, ids) 
    values (%s, %s::lang[])
    ''', ["person1",["english","hindi"]])
)
```